Commits not pulled automatically in YouTrack integrated with GitLab running in Docker containers on same host with different ports
I have YouTrack and GitLab running on separate Docker containers on the same host machine, using different ports, and have set up VCS integration in YouTrack with GitLab. The import works fine, and I can see the commits in the YouTrack issues, but when I make a commit in GitLab with the issue ID, the commit does not get pulled automatically into YouTrack, unless I add the commit hash manually to the issue.
YouTrack setup:
sudo docker run -it --name youtrack \
...
-p 9000:8080 \
-p 8443:8443 \
jetbrains/youtrack:2024.1.29548

GitLab setup:
sudo docker run --detach \
--hostname mydomain \
--publish 9100:9100 --publish 9143:9143 --publish 9122:22 \
--name gitlab \
...
gitlab/gitlab-ce:16.9.6-ce.0

Enabled the relevant ports on the host machine:
sudo ufw allow 9000/tcp comment 'Http access for YouTrack'
sudo ufw allow 8443/tcp comment 'Https access for YouTrack'
sudo ufw allow 9100/tcp comment 'Http access for GitLab'
sudo ufw allow 9143/tcp comment 'Https access for GitLab'
sudo ufw allow 9122/tcp comment 'SSH access for GitLab'

Both YouTrack and GitLab are using SSL and the same signed CA certificate. The same keystore was also added during the VCS integration setup.
The sites can be accessed in the browser by:

YouTrack - https://mydomain:8443
GitLab - https://mydomain:9143

I went to GitLab > my project > Settings > Webhooks and tested the project hooks that go to YouTrack, e.g. https://mydomain:8443/api/vcsHooksReceiver/gitlab/205-109, and got an error like:
Hook execution failed: Failed to open TCP connection to mydomain:8443 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "mydomain" port 8443)

When I enter the GitLab container shell and try to access the YouTrack URL, it fails to connect. However, it is able to connect to other URLs including its own.
$ sudo docker exec -it gitlab /bin/bash
gitlab-container$ curl https://mydomain:8443
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mydomain port 8443 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server
gitlab-container$ curl https://mydomain:9143
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://mydomain:9143/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>

When I tested the same webhook, with the 'mydomain' replaced with the IP, it gave a different error:
Hook execution failed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=[youtrack IP]:8443 state=error: certificate verify failed (Hostname mismatch)

This made me think that the hostname of YouTrack was not recognized by GitLab, so I tried to change the hostname on YouTrack, using methods described by https://forums.docker.com/t/change-hostname-of-an-existing-container/361/16 and another method by updating the 'Hostname' value in /var/lib/docker/containers/[container_id]/config.v2.json, and restarting the container and Docker. The hostname got changed in YouTrack container at /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts. However, the problem remains.
